# sed command to replace string not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

Must be doing something silly here.

I have a file called 'test'.
The file contains only one line -

```
versionName '2.0.0'
```

I want to programmatically replace the 2.0.0 value dynamically.
Can't figure out why the following command not working -

```
sed -i '' 's/versionName  "[0-9.]*"/versionName "'${MAJOR_VERSION}'"/' test
```

here, MAJOR_VERSION is a variable.

Please let me know if I can provide more info.

Comment: What is actually happening?  What does `echo "$MAJOR_VERSION"` show you?

Comment: same value as it was before - 2.0.0

Comment: Re *`sed -i '' ...`* - That looks like OS X (a.k.a. MacOS), not Linux. Are you certain you are on Linux? Otherwise I would expect GNU sed to produce an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sed -i '' "s/versionName '[0-9.]*'/versionName '${MAJOR_VERSION}'/" test
```

There were a couple of issues :

- Your line had single-quotes, but your sed command was trying to match on double-quotes
- Your line had a single space, but your sed command had two-spaces

eg:

```
 $ export MAJOR_VERSION=xyz
 % echo "versionName '2.0.0'" > test
 $ sed -i '' "s/versionName '[0-9.]*'/versionName '${MAJOR_VERSION}'/" test
 $ cat test
```

results in :

```
versionName 'xyz'
```

Comment: Strange, I've just rerun on mine, copy/pasting both the test line and my answer, and the value is updated as expected.

Comment: it works now....I don't know why it was not working sometime before. Marking it as an answer.